Translating and rotating a shape to vertices on a layer
I'm trying to generate a swept path for a ship, our simulator can export lat/long and heading coordinates(and more).
In QGIS I did something with the Rectangles, Ovals and Diamonds tool which lets me draw a shape the height and width I need at each point and apply a heading...the issue is a ship isn't quite any of those shapes.
I was thinking I could create an SVG the shape of the ship but is there a tool that would let me place them as the vertex points and rotate them?  Or can I somehow convert the outlines to a polygon if I used them as symbols?  I also have ArcGIS Pro by the way which is an option as well.
----------------Updated 5/3/2024----------------------------
Here's an example of what I'm trying to get...this is from the Rectangles, Ovals and Diamonds tool...unfortunately the ship tappers in the front creating distortions in the shape.  I can then however take this shape and dissolve it into a single polygon.
I was thinking I could use an SVG symbol to do something similar with the original veticies but I'd still need to convert the entire outline of all those symbols into a single polygon in the end.


I did find a tool as well called Create Line of Bearing which will create a line of a given length at each vertex with the heading attribute for the rotation...I can create a second line at the heading attribute+180 to to get the other side...if I could create a specific set of cross section lines which would vary in length to match that of the ship I'd be in business as well.

You can use SVG as point markers. Maybe that makes things easier.

I couldn't figure out a way to create the outline from them as a polygon...also the scaling was off even though I set the dimensions in meters at scale.  That was my alternative plan though.

This finally came to me after seeing another post or two and some talking with chatgpt.  I needed to create the feature at the origin, rotate it and as the vertex points read in move it to the spot.
